# Iteration results in fixed-size groups

Tags: python, python-itertools

I can iterate over a list or string in fixed-size slices like this:

```
for n in range(0, len(somelongstring), 10):
    print(somelongstring[n:n+10])
```

But how do I iterate over 10-line slices from an open file, or over some other iterable, without reading the whole thing into a list? Every so often I need to do this, and there *must* be a straightforward formula using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), but there is *nothing* similar in the itertools documentation, and I can't google it or figure it out and I end up solving the problem some other way. What am I missing?

```
with open("filename.txt") as source:
    for tenlinegroup in ten_at_a_time_magic(source, 10):
         print(...)
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a straightforward way, as there is no "generic" way to combine the 10 items back to 1 that can be yielded. I guess in your example you expect them to be combined by "\n" or put in a list or something else.

Comment: List, tuple or sub-iterable, yes. Not combined into a string (even if the elements are strings), that would be up to the consuming code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally remembered that the term for this is "chunking", and then I was able to track it down, in the itertools [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) no less. Boiled down, it's this head-spinning little trick with `zip` (actually `zip_longest`, but who's counting):

```
def chunk(source, n):
    return zip_longest(*([iter(source)] * n))
```

First you take *n* references to the same iterator and bundle them into a list; then you unpack this list (with `*`) as arguments to `zip_longest`. When it's used, each tuple returned by `zip_longest` is filled from *n* successive calls to the iterator.

```
>>> for row in chunk(range(10), 3):
...     print(row)

(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, None, None)
```

See the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (look for `grouper`) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434411/699305) for variations on the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions is that, if you need such a function regularly, why not write it yourself. Here is an example how I would code it:

```
def slice_into_lists(iterable, groupsize):
    rv = []
    count = 0
    for i in iterable:
        rv.append(i)
        count += 1
        if count % groupsize == 0:
            yield rv
            rv = []
    if rv:
        yield rv
```

Of course instead of returning a list, you could also return something different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got me interested, so I worked on a solution that would not copy anything but only use the original iterator. Posting it here as it relates directly to the question.

```
class ichunk:
    ''' An iterable wrapper that raises StopIteration every chunksize+1'th call to __next__ '''

    def __init__(self, iterable, chunksize, fill_last_chunk, fill_value):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.stopinterval = chunksize+1
        self.counter = 0
        self.has_ended = False
        self.fill_last = fill_last_chunk
        self.fill_value = fill_value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.counter > 0 and self.counter % self.stopinterval == 0:
            self.counter += 1
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            self.counter += 1
            nexti = next(self.it)
            return nexti
        except StopIteration as e:
            self.has_ended = True
            if (not self.fill_last) or (self.counter % self.stopinterval == 0):
                raise e
            else:
                return self.fill_value


def ichunker(iterable, chunksize, *, fill_last_chunk=False, fill_value=None):
    c = ichunk(iterable, chunksize, fill_last_chunk, fill_value)
    while not c.has_ended:
        yield c
```

So rather then using the returned value from `ichunker`, you iterate over it again like:

```
    with open("filename") as fp:
        for chunk in ichunker(fp, 10):
            print("------ start of Chunk -------")
            for line in chunk:
                print("--> "+line.strip())
            print("------ End of Chunk -------")
        print("End of iteration")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `more_itertools`.
Straight from [the documentation](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.ichunked):

```
>>> from more_itertools import ichunk
>>> from itertools import count
>>> all_chunks = ichunked(count(), 4)
>>> c_1, c_2, c_3 = next(all_chunks), next(all_chunks), next(all_chunks)
>>> list(c_2)  # c_1's elements have been cached; c_3's haven't been
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(c_1)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(c_3)
[8, 9, 10, 11]
```

You can choose between `ichunk`, which breaks an iterable into n sub-iterables, or `chunk`, which returns n sub-lists.

Answer (score -1):

Use `itertools.islice` with `enumerate` like this

```
import itertools
some_long_string = "ajbsjabdabdkabda"
for n in itertools.islice(enumerate(some_long_string), 0, None ,10):
    print(some_long_string[n[0]:n[0]+10])
# output
ajbsjabdab
dkabda
```

If you are dealing with file then you can use chunk while file.read() like this

```
# for file 
with open("file1.txt", ) as f:
    for n in itertools.islice(enumerate(f.read(10000)), 0, 1000 ,5):
        print(n[1])
```

Comment: Thanks but the point is that you _cannot_ index into just any iterable. How do you apply a slice to the iterator returned by `open()`? (Anyway you don't need enumerate here, notice that you never use `n[1]`)

Comment: Enumerate is used for getting index , thatswhy i have used n[0] to get the index of start of string , n[1] will be value of string?

Comment: With open() you need to pass some iterator to enumerate you can pass the file pointer received with open() to enumerate ?

Comment: yes, the file pointer is an iterable, it returns one line at a time.