# Build a matrix from a string of number separated by space

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers in a string separated by space x="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ..."
I want to extract 3x3 matrices (list of list) from this string so the above string should produce the output = [ [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[ [10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18] ]...
I tried using the split function on the variable x and loop over it to build the final output but it gets messy. `Is there a simple way to do it in simple python or using some library?`
We can assume that the number of elements will be consistent with splitting it into 3x3 and the numbers are separated by single space

Comment: Is the total number of elements in `x` always consistent with splitting into `3x3` matrices? Are elements in `x` always separated by a single space?

Comment: numpy.reshape would be an option if you are using numpy.

Comment: @d.b yes we can assume that

Answer (score 0):

With NymPy, this is quite easy.

First, use `str.split()` to get a list of the numbers, cast them to ints (or floats if you need), and then reshape the array:

```
import numpy as np

s = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17'

a = np.array([int(x) for x in s.split()]).reshape((-1,3))
```

yields

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

while

```
a = np.array([int(x) for x in s.split()]).reshape((3,-1))
```

yields

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

And if you know both dimensions of the results, pass them explicitly to `reshape()` instead of my `-1` (which means that one dimension is left unspecified).

Answer (score 0):

Taking the `chunk`-implementation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165798/iteration-results-in-fixed-size-groups/74167264#74167264) answer, you can just apply it twice to get 3x3 matrixes:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def chunk(source, n):
    return zip_longest(*([iter(source)] * n))

string = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18"
matrix = list(chunk(chunk(string.split(" "), 3), 3))
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18"
x_arr = [int(el) for el in x.split(" ")]

def foo(arr, n):
    return [arr[i:(i + n)] for i in range(0, len(arr), n)]

[foo(el, 3) for el in foo(x_arr, 9)]
# [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a library that is designed to easily do this.

Using base python with numpy:

1. Parse the string into sets of 3 or insert a semi-colon after every third element.
2. Use numpy's matrix operation, np.matrix() on each set of three.
3. Use a control structure to only operate on 3 sets of elements at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your vector in chunks of the right size and use [numpy's reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
vector = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18"
n = 3
matrix_size = 3*3

vector = np.array([int(x) for x in vector.split()])

matrixes = [vector[i-matrix_size:i].reshape((n,n)) for i in range(matrix_size,len(vector)+1,matrix_size)]

matrixes

[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]),
        array([[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]])]
```